# How to set font attributes for all text in a chart?

Tags: json, coldfusion, styling, zingchart

I have a ZingChart (through cfchart) that has an external JSON styling file. How can I set font attributes, such as font-family, font-weight, font-size for all text in the chart, without setting it individually?

My JSON file so far:

```
{
"graphset":[
    {       
        "background-color":"white",
        "font-family":"Courier New",
        "scale-x":{
            "label":{
                "text":"Date"
            }
        },
        "scale-y":{
            "label":{
                "text":"Score"
            },
            "markers":[
                {
                    "type":"line",
                    "range":[75,76],
                    "line-color":"red"
                },
                {
                    "type":"line",
                    "range":[50,51],
                    "line-color":"yellow"
                }
            ]
        },
        "tooltip" : {
            "text" : "Score of %v on %k",
            "background-color" : "#ff9900"
        },
        "plot":{
            "marker":{
                "type":"square"
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that I can add it individually for, say, all scale-x "item"s":

```
"scale-x":{
            "label":{
                "text":"Date"
            },
             "item":{ 
                "font-angle":320,
                "font-family":"Arial",
                "font-weight":"bold",
                "font-size":13
            }
        }
```

But I want to add it for all text in the chart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CSS descendant selectors to do this. Use your chart div's id and the tspan element selector to apply font-family, font-weight, font-size, etc..., to all of the text elements in a chart. Example for a chart render at div id="zc":

```
<style>
#zc tspan { font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive !important;font-weight:bold !important;font-size:12px !important; }
</style>
```

[Demo here](http://zingchart.com/playground/run/533dbdfc74991)

Sorry for the confusion, here's a non-CSS solution:

Within your chart JSON object, place the "globals" object with the desired global attributes in the root level (same level as "graphset"):

```
  {      
    "globals":{
      "font-size":20,
      "font-family":"Papyrus"
    },
    "graphset":[
      {
        "type":"line",
        ...
      }
    ]
  };
```

[New demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nmastracchio/vym3dzdj/2/)

Comment: I guess I didn't make this clear enough - this is a ZingChart styling file. I need the ZingChart options, not CSS. I'll update my post.

Comment: I'm doing this through a cfchart so I'm not sure how to incorporate that code. I have `<cfchart format="html" style="myStyles.js">` and then the code I posted in the myStyles.js file. Where would I put the theme code?

Comment: In that case, you'll want to put the "globals" object in the root level, so the same level as your "graphset" array.

Comment: Ok, I added the globals object within the graphset object and it's working! thank you! (Maybe update your answer with that info)

Comment: Interesting - I actually added it within the graphset object and it worked. I haven't tried putting it at the same level

Answer (score -1):

You can also select all elements on the page with the * (wildcard character)

For example:

```
* { font-family: Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive !important;font-weight:bold !important;font-size:12px !important; }
```

Comment: A little more explanation on why/how this works would lead me (and possibly others) to want to upvote this answer

Comment: It is a wild card character that selects all elements. It is used as a CSS Selector. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Ok, but the OP and [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483919/how-to-set-font-attributes-for-all-text-in-a-chart#comment45295732_28485736) indicate they were looking for a Zing charts setting, rather than CSS.